# influxdb: unclear usage of tsi1 index after upgrading from in-memory type

Tags: influxdb

influxdb 1.5.2

I've tried switching from inmem index type to tsi1 according documentation

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/administration/upgrading/#switching-from-in-memory-tsm-based-index-to-disk-tsi-based-index

- change `index-version = "tsi1"` in config file
- stop influxdb
- run index migration for all data `sudo -H -u influxdb bash -c 'influx_inspect buildtsi -datadir /var/lib/influxdb/data -waldir /var/lib/influxdb/wal/'`
- run influxdb service

Index dirs were created but system start using even more memory than previous :(

Also I've checked modification date of files inside index dir and it wasn't changed after hours (the same time when I complete buildtsi command).

How I can be sure that influxdb start using new index type?

I see that devs work on visibility in new versions of influxdb

- https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/pull/9777
- https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/9707

But now (in 1.5.x version) it's absolutely unclear for me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the index was build sucessfully. 
If your memory is not sufficient the build process will killed from the out of memory detection mechanism before it successfully ends.
Infludb will then ignore the incomplete index files and use inmem index instead.

Check /var/log/messages for OOM kills.